# IE letting URLS break the containing DIV, but FF shows fine. Fix?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, url

So im integrating this Twitter widget into xhtml.

( http://help.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15354 )

The code is:

```
<dl id="twitter_update_list"></dl>
```

...then a couple lines of javascript.

Heres the issue. Why would IE display long urls (links within the list item) as breaking the containing DIV? Meanwhile FF just continues the url onto the next line, nice and clean. Any idea?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how IE "breaks" the DIV?  Are you just saying that long URLs go beyond the specified length of the DIV?  If so, that happens for me in both IE and FF, so a couple screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: ya thats what im saying. 

http://www.albuquerquecupcakecreations.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `word-wrap: break-word;` in your CSS. It's an IE only property, but I don't see a problem in FF.

Correction: it used to be an IE only property, I see now it's been added to CSS3 and is supported by IE, Safari, and FF.